UIAutomationを使ってWindowOpenedイベントを取得できない
ある株取引ソフトをタイマーで起動させ、ログインウィンドウが表示されたら通知するようなものを開発しています。
WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEventを使えばいいと思い、Automation.AddAutomationEventHandlerで実装してみましたがWindowOpenedが発火してもなにも表示されません。
WindowOpenedが発火していないのかと思いましたが、AccEventで確認したところWindowOpenedは確かに発火していました。
また、この株取引ソフトはClickOnceであるため、起動するとまずアップデート確認ウィンドウが一瞬開き、その後でログインウィンドウが開くようになっています。今回検知したいのは、後で開く、ログインウィンドウの方です
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Text;


void onWindowOpened(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
{
    AutomationElement? element;
    try
    {
        element = sender as AutomationElement;
        if (element == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element is null");
        } else
        {
                Console.WriteLine("onWindowOpened!!");
        }
    }
    catch (ElementNotAvailableException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ElementNotAvailableException is happened");
    }
}



Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, AutomationElement.RootElement, TreeScope.Subtree, new AutomationEventHandler(onWindowOpened));
    KillKabuS();
    var p = StartKabuS();
    LoginKabucom(p);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);



void KillKabuS()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        if (process.ProcessName.Contains("KabuS"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("KabuS is included");
            process.Kill(true);
            process.WaitForExit();
            break;
        }
    }
}

Process? StartKabuS()
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    var appref = "C:\\Users\\yuya\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\kabu.com\\kabuステーション.appref-ms";
    psi.FileName = appref;
    psi.UseShellExecute = true;
    var p = Process.Start(psi);
    return p;
}

void LoginKabucom(Process? kabus)
{
    if (kabus != null)
    {
        var cond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "ログイン");
        var elem = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, cond);
        if (elem == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("window not found");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Elem has been found");
        }
    }
}


この記事が何か参考になるかも。UI AutomationでWindowsプログラムの自動化などしてみる
